# How to get ssh information automatically in phpstorm remote server list?

Tags: macos, ssh, ftp, phpstorm

I have to work with lots of remote server for different projects.

It's too much annoying to update the same ssh informations every time for *ssh terminal*, *phpstorm*,  *filezilla*, *sequel pro* and others.

Is there any way, so that phpstorm can get the ssh config file information automatically?
Then I just need to select the remote server from the dropdown menu.

Better, if possible also for filezilla and sequel pro.

For ssh terminal, I use [shuttle](https://github.com/fitztrev/shuttle)